# Trying to get positive or negative difference in window in postgresql query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table, `daily`, as follows:

```
|date|high|low|
```

I am attempting to return the max positive or negative difference for each N day window of the data. For example, the following query gets me very close for a 5 day window:

```
SELECT date, high, low, (high - low) AS diff
FROM (
  SELECT dd.date AS date,
    MAX(dd.high)
      OVER(ORDER BY dd.date ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS high,
    MIN(dd.low)
      OVER(ORDER BY dd.date ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS low
  FROM daily dd
) AS win
ORDER BY date
```

However, this query is not correct because the result will always be positive. If the high occurred before the low, the result should be negative. Is there a way to accomplish this with a query?

EDIT: Adding examples and expected result

EDIT2: Modified with better example

```
|date      |high|low|
|01-01-2001|20  |10 |
|01-02-2001|30  |20 |
|01-03-2001|40  |30 |
|01-04-2001|30  |25 |
|01-05-2001|35  |25 |
```

Result for 5 day period should be:

```
|date      |high|low|diff|
|01-01-2001|20  |10 |10  |
|01-02-2001|30  |10 |20  |
|01-03-2001|40  |10 |30  |
|01-04-2001|40  |10 |30  |
|01-05-2001|40  |10 |30  |
```

Result for 3 day period should be:

```
|01-01-2001|20  |10 |10  |
|01-02-2001|30  |10 |20  |
|01-03-2001|40  |10 |10  |
|01-04-2001|40  |20 |20  |
|01-05-2001|40  |25 |-15 |
```

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result too?

Comment: Added sample data with expected results.

Comment: What about there are two rows have the same lowest or highest value but different date?

Comment: @ToBeFrank . . . Your sample data doesn't help so much.  Your original query returns one value per row.  Your example returns one row per five values.  It also doesn't explain what to do when the high and low are on the same date.

Comment: Modified with better example

Comment: @D-Shih it's not much of a concern in the real data so whatever that case returns is fine

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a subquery to get the highest and lowest value from daily table. then do `SELF JOIN` with `CASE WHEN`

```
CREATE TABLE daily(
    date date,
    high int,
    low int
);


INSERT INTO daily VALUES ('01-01-2001',40 ,30);
INSERT INTO daily VALUES ('01-02-2001',30 ,25);
INSERT INTO daily VALUES ('01-03-2001',35 ,25);
INSERT INTO daily VALUES ('01-04-2001',20 ,10);
INSERT INTO daily VALUES ('01-05-2001',30 ,20);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT  t1.*,
        CASE WHEN highdt.date > lowdt.date 
           THEN highest - lowest 
           ELSE lowest - highest 
        END diff
FROM (
  select MAX(date) dates,
         MAX(high) highest,
         MIN(low)  lowest
  from daily
) t1
JOIN  daily highdt ON t1.highest = highdt.high
JOIN  daily lowdt ON t1.lowest = lowdt.low;

| dates                    | highest | lowest | diff |
| ------------------------ | ------- | ------ | ---- |
| 2001-01-05T00:00:00.000Z | 40      | 10     | -30  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xwEsndestwPmTEsr4JFivy/0)